# The parameter already belongs to a collection. Как добавить параметр в коллекцию?

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql

Добавил две строчки в код:

```
 string posRoot = new Common(ASP.AppGlobal.PgSQLConn).ReturnData(pgsqlParams, Resources.PgSQLResources.GetPosById);
 WReport.Report.SetParameterValue("PrmBranch", posRoot);
```

При компиляции кода, выходит ошибка, в которой сказано, что параметр уже принадлежит коллекции. Что за коллекция и как исправить это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

StackTrace:

> в PgSQL.DataPgSQL.Common.ReturnData(NpgsqlParameter[] pgsqlParams,
>   String pgsqlProc)    в RepWorkRequest.WReport_StartReport(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) в
>   c:\DevProjects\ARM_Metrolog_v2_pg\Source\ARM_Metrolog\Services\RepWorkRequest.aspx.cs:строка
>   55    в FastReport.Web.WebReport.OnStartReport(EventArgs e)    в
>   FastReport.Web.WebReport.ReportRegisterDataAndRunEvent()    в
>   FastReport.Web.WebReport.ReportProcess(StringBuilder sb, HttpContext
>   context)    в FastReport.Web.WebReport.GetReportHTML(StringBuilder sb,
>   HttpContext context)    в
>   FastReport.Web.Handlers.WebExport.SendReport(HttpContext context)

Comment: текст ошибки и стектрейс не помешало бы добавить в вопрос

Comment: добавил текст ошибки в заголовок.

Comment: используете какую версию npgsql?

Comment: Npgsql ver. 2.2.7

Comment: актуальная версия - 3.2.6, обновитесь и проверьте результат, у них был баг

Comment: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/214

Comment: Кстати, там вроде бы поддерживается connection pooling, так что, как и для всех других ado.net провайдеров, держать один статический NpgsqlConnection не стоит - его нужно создавать на каждое обращение к базе, и оборачивать использование в using (если Common у вас - это именно Connection, по коду непонятно :)

Comment: @DmitryNikitin - *обновитесь и проверьте результат* - помогло?

Comment: Ещё не обновился. Отпишусь.